# Draw9patch are not shown correctly

Tags: android, nine-patch

I have a problem with my 9patch images. I use 9patch images for months without problem but now, some of my images don't want to work normaly anymore.
The problem is that some images are showed like if they wasn't 9patched and I can see the black pixels around the image on my device's screen.

I tried to solve the problem by cleaning the project but nothing changed.

Did somebody have this problem? How can I solve it?

Thank you

PS: Sorry for my poor English, I speak frensh :-)

Solution:
I just find the solution. I deleted all my images from my drawable folder and rewrite they in it.

Thanks

Comment: Bienvenue sur StackOverflow ;) We need to see your 9-patch images to be able to help, please post one of them that has this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is a 9patch in a library.  There is a knowen issue up for a [problem](http://tools.android.com/knownissues) as of the tools relase 14.

No good solution though apart from some forced cleaning.